# Adobe Encore/Premier quick and dirty/shortcut to make DVD

Tags: video, premiere, encore

Isn't there a quick way to create a DVD movie with menus and everything in Adobe Encore or Premier? I mean like for instance the old iDVD on Macs where you could choose a preexisting theme and iDVD would do the rest for you (once you've chosen the chapters etc).

Comment: Have you found the answer to solve your problem? If you have, please mark it as "Correct". This makes your question a valuable reference for other members of this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Adobe CC, Adobe removed a program from their Premiere suite called *Encore*. Encore had all the same benefits of Dynamic Link - you didn't need to render your project, just add your project file, and boom - transcoded to DVD in one step, without an intermediate.

Now, for CC users, you still have a licence for CS6, and can downloaded Encore still, through the Creative Cloud launcher.

What you do have to do, is first make an intermediate render. You've got two basic choices:

1. Render a Master copy, full res, full quality, with no or very little compression (ProRes, DNxHD etc.)
2. Render a DVD-ready MPEG2, that will not need transcoding in Encore. There are presets for this in Media Encoder.

Adobe has the information you'll need to download Encore in their [Help Documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/encore/kb/encore-cs6-installed-cc.html). Summarised, you install Premiere CS6, which also installs Encore CS6. Then, uninstalling *only* Premiere will leave you with Encore CS6, as well as all your regular Adobe CC apps.